# How would I go about backing up the Windows Application Log at a regular interval?

Tags: windows, logging, batch-file, backup, event-viewer

I'm working with an application that logs to Windows Application Log regularly (viewable through the Event Viewer administrative tool), and I'm looking for a way to back it up on a daily basis. This is important because we sometimes discover a problem with the application - and to investigate further we need information that was logged a week ago. The events we are looking for aren't necessarily still around ... I've tried increasing the size and all that, but I think an automated backup would facilitate the process. We wouldn't end up with huge logs, but rather, multiple moderately-sized logs.

I would *prefer* a simple solution like batch file + Windows Scheduler, but would also be interested in other approaches.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a WMI script that I found a while ago.  This could be what you're searching!

```
dim strComputer = "." 'Define here the Remote IP Address or Computername
dim objWMIService
dim colLogFiles
dim objLogfile
dim errBackupLog

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Backup)}!\\" &  strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Call eventlogbackup("Application")
Call eventlogbackup("System")
Call eventlogbackup("Security")

Function eventlogbackup(logtype)

Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventLogFile WHERE LogFileName='" & logtype & "'")

For Each objLogfile in colLogFiles
 errBackupLog = objLogFile.BackupEventLog("\\server\eventlogs\" & strComputer & "\" &logtype & ".evt")
 If errBackupLog <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "The " & logtype &" event log could not be backed up."
 Else
    objLogFile.ClearEventLog()
    Wscript.Echo "The " & logtype &" event log is backed up."
 End If
Next

End Function
```

Just set-up this script in a scheduled task and you're good to go!

Comment: Looks promising - I'll give this a shot when I have a chance, and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) to read the event log and do whatever you like with the result.  Here's an [article](http://www.siccolo.com/Articles/CodeProject/LogWatcher_RSS_feed/build_log_watcher_rss_feed_using_WMI.html) that you may be able to tweak to your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Output all events in the Application channel, to XML:

```
wevtutil.exe qe application
```

For readable text output, use:

```
wevtutil.exe qe application /f:text
```

You could easily pipe either of these outputs to a file periodically for backup.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider setting up one of the tools to forward windows events to a syslog server.  Then instead of having to run a process that does the backup you will get all the log entries forwarded to a second location nearly at the same time they are added to the windows event log.

http://ntsyslog.sourceforge.net/
http://edoceo.com/creo/winlogd
http://www.softpanorama.org/Logs/Syslog/syslog_for_windows.shtml

Depending on what syslog server you use you can setup filters to ignore some events or send them to different files. You can setup log rolling however you like.